# Executing stored procedure in MS Access through ADO connection - removing application role

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ado

I have an app developed in MS Access which uses ADO connections to SQL server (Microsoft SQL Server 2017) to execute numerous stored procedures. The ADO connections are all done through an application role in order to limit permissions.

In the latest update, I created a few new stored procedures which return several recordsets, which are pasted in Excel. My issue is that when I execute these stored procedures, the application role is removed... The query runs without any issues, but when it finishes running, the application role is unset.

The following is an example of one of the stored procs being called in VBA Access:

```
Public Function CDTExceptionsReport() As ADODB.Recordset

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set objConn = DB.MaintainConnection

    On Error GoTo 0

    If objCmd_ER Is Nothing Then
        Set objCmd_ER = New ADODB.Command
        With objCmd_ER
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandTimeout = 60 ' increase command 
            .CommandText = "EXEC tool.ExceptionsReport;"
            .Prepared = True
            ' set connection object
            .ActiveConnection = objConn

        End With
    End If

    Set CDTExceptionsReport = objCmd_ER.Execute

    On Error GoTo 0
     Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.DESCRIPTION & vbNewLine & "Number: " & Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0 ' reset error handling
End Function
```

Note that `objConn` is my connection object, and `objCmd_ER` is my global command object.

Through the immediate terminal in VBA, I can check what role is being activated by using the following in debug mode:

```
Set RS = objConn.Execute("SELECT CURRENT_USER")
?RS.Fields(0)
```

If I run this before the `objCmd_ER.Execute` line, I can see the application role is still in use. However, when I run this immediately after that statement, the application role is removed and my windows username is returned. Has anyone experienced this before?

I've executed this stored procedure in SQL Server directly, and it works fine and does not log the application role out. Therefore my thinking is it's something to do with the ADO connection.

Please let me know what further details would be helpful to provide. The stored procedure does not contain any DDL or DML language - just 4 select queries.

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that application roles do not play nice with connection pooling. Use `sp_unsetapprole` before you close the connection as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/creating-application-roles-in-sql-server).

Comment: Thanks, @DanGuzman - there are quite a few stored procedures that get repeatedly executed. Are you suggesting I have to set and unset the approle before and after (respectively) every stored proc I call? Due to what I mentioned here, I tend to not close the connection as the next stored proc is never longer than 30s away.

Comment: Not set/unset before ach call but set after each connection open and unset just before connection close /close. Otherwise, you'll need to disable connection pooling.

Comment: I do set the application role after a connection is opened. I never close connections; I assume they eventually time-out. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Connection pooling with application roles will be a non-issue if you never close connections or turn off pooling via the connection string. I suspect the problem you are having is because ADO is opening connections behind your back because the specified connection is already in use. Run `SELECT @@SPID;` in the debugger to see if the session id is different.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks against for your help. Unfortunately, no joy - the SPID stays the same, but the CURRENT_USER changes after me executing a stored proc from the app role to my login name... The stored procedure has nothing to do with setting/unsetting application roles, it consists of a bunch of select queries.

Comment: Try running a trace (Profiler or Extended Events) capturing login, logout, batch_completed, and rpc_completed events. That will capture the actual requests executed by the API and hopefully indicate how to app role it's getting unset.

Comment: Thanks, @DanGuzman - this helped me find the problem! When I ran the trace, I noticed that it captured the following: 

-- 'sp_setapprole' was found in the text of this event. 
-- The text has been replaced with this comment for security reasons.

Do you reckon if I execute the invoking of the app role differently, it would solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with how `sp_setapprole` is executed. Review the trace for subsequent activity on the same session after `sp_setapprole`. I'd expect that to provide clues as to how/why the app role context is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Never do this!

`.ActiveConnection = objConn`

That casts the connection object `objConn` to a connection string, then creates a new connection using that connection string, and uses that as the active connection.

Instead, always do this:

`Set .ActiveConnection = objConn`

That actually sets the active connection to your connection object.

Comment: Thanks, Erik. Unfortunately this didn't make the error go away...

Comment: Hi Nick. I am trying to connect to a SQL Server using ADO and also using an Application Role. I am able to connect to the server using a simple user. I created an application role but it does not work "Login failed for user 'testApp'". Can you tell how to configure the application role and the connection string you used?